# Does the fundamental theorem of calculus hold for "inverted" intervals?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

Consider a continuous and Riemann integrable function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ and fix $a\in\mathbb{R}$. If we define now $F:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}, x\mapsto\int_{a}^{x}f(y)dy$, is it true that $F$ is differentiable and $F'(x)=f(x)$, for $x<a$?

---

I know the standard fundamental theorem which yields a positive answer to the above but only for $x\ge a$. What about the other case?

I have tried writing $F(x)=-\int_{x}^{a}f(y)dy$ and applying the fundamental theorem of calculus but that doesn't seem to work since the lower bound now varies.

Comment: @SangchulLee Perfect, thanks. If you would post that as an answer I would accept it.

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(Migrated from the comment)*

Note that you can write

$$ F(x) = \int_{b}^{x} f(y) \, \mathrm{d}y - \int_{b}^{a} f(y) \, \mathrm{d}y $$

for any $b \in \mathbb{R}$. So, if you wish to establish the differentiability of $F$ at $x_0$, then you may choose $b$ to be less than $x_0$ and then apply the fundamental theorem of calculus.